# convert a recursive algorithm into a non-recursive implementation

Tags: recursion

```
public void selectString(List<List<String>> candidateList, List<String> selected, List<List<String>> results, int target) {

    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(candidateList)){
        return;
    }

    List<String> candidate = candidateList.get(0);

    for (String oneCandidate : candidate){
        if (selected.contains(oneCandidate)) continue;

        List<String> currentSelected = new ArrayList<>();
        currentSelected.addAll(selected);
        currentSelected.add(oneCandidate);

        if (currentSelected.size() >= target){
            results.add(currentSelected);
        }

        this.selectString(candidateList.subList(1, candidateList.size()), currentSelected, results, target);
    }

    return;
}
```

The above code is a permutations recursive algorithm I wrote,candidateList represents the source list,selected is an empty list at the beginning,results represent the final results,target represents the size of candidateList.How can I convert my permutations recursive algorithm into a non-recursive implementation?

Comment: Hi F.Li, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  What have you tried so far?  Generally, people will be more likely to help you solve your problem if you show us what you've tried on your own first, even if those attempts have failed.  Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: I tried to implement this conversion with loops and stacks, but it failed because my recursion is written in a loop, which makes the problem look a lot more complicated, so I am here to ask for help.